# XML deserialisation: how to get the entity code instead of the element?

Tags: xml, vb.net, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I'm attempting to deserialise an XML file, which is a Japanese to English dictionary, so that I can display the information in a Windows Form. I am still not too clued up on how XML and deserialisation generally works, so please be patient if I mistake terminology.

My code deserialises the XML dictionary just fine, and I can access all the information for each entry. However, sometimes I want to access some information stored in the XML file as an entity code(?), rather than the underlying element(?), and I don't know how to do that.

Here's an example of what I mean:

In the XML file, the `<pos>` tag is used to store information about the part of speech of an entry (adjective, noun and so on.) This information is stored in a List(Of String) for each individual entry (as one entry might record more than one part of speech.) If I were to view the part of speech data for an individual entry, it might look like this:

```
    (0) "noun (common) (futsuumeishi)"  
    (1) "noun or participle which takes the aux. verb suru" 
    (2) "nouns which may take the genitive case particle `no'"
```

Now this is verbose, and I don't want all this information when I'm displaying an entry on screen. I'm fine with the shorthand code used in the XML file itself, which would represent the above three items as `&n;`, `&vs;` and `&adj-no;` respectively. When the deserialiser comes across these elements, it translates them into the verbose form described in the attribute list at the top of the file, rather than the short form that I want.

The XML for one particular entry containing these `pos` tags looks like this:

```
<entry>
<ent_seq>1371320</ent_seq>
<k_ele>
<keb>水泳</keb>
<ke_pri>ichi1</ke_pri>
<ke_pri>news1</ke_pri>
<ke_pri>nf07</ke_pri>
</k_ele>
<r_ele>
<reb>すいえい</reb>
<re_pri>ichi1</re_pri>
<re_pri>news1</re_pri>
<re_pri>nf07</re_pri>
</r_ele>
<sense>
<!-- These are the tags I'm interested in -->
<pos>&n;</pos>
<pos>&vs;</pos>
<pos>&adj-no;</pos>
<gloss>swimming</gloss>
</sense>
...
...
</entry>
```

Here's a snippet of the attribute list containing the data for the `pos` tag:

```
<!ENTITY adj-no "nouns which may take the genitive case particle `no'">
...
<!ENTITY n "noun (common) (futsuumeishi)">
...
<!ENTITY vs "noun or participle which takes the aux. verb suru">
```

Here's the class object which I use to deserialise the `sense` element, which contains the `pos` element:

```
<Serializable()>
<XmlType("sense")>
Public Class SenseElement
    <XmlElement("pos")>
    Public Property PartOfSpeech As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("gloss")>
    Public Property Gloss As List(Of GlossElement)

    <XmlElement("stagk")>
    Public Property SenseRestrictedToKeyword As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("stagr")>
    Public Property SenseRestrictedToReading As List(Of String)

    <XmlElement("xref")>
    Public Property CrossReference As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("ant")>
    Public Property Antonym As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("field")>
    Public Property Field As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("dial")>
    Public Property Dialect As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("s_inf")>
    Public Property SenseInformation As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("misc")>
    Public Property Misc As List(Of String)
    <XmlElement("lsource")>
    Public Property LanguageSource As List(Of LanguageSourceElement)
End Class
```

And lastly, here's the deserialiser:

```
Sub Deserialise()
    Dim settings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse

    Dim xmlPath As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, jmdictpath)

    Dim serialiser As New XmlSerializer(GetType(JMdict))

    Using rdr As Xml.XmlReader = Xml.XmlReader.Create(xmlPath, settings)
        dict = CType(serialiser.Deserialize(rdr), JMdict)
    End Using
End Sub
```

So the question is, how can I extract the short form of the data for the `pos` tag contained in the XML file, rather than the long form contained in the attribute list? Is there a simple fix to do this? I'd most prefer an answer in VB.NET, but so long as the solution is explained well enough it's not too important.

Also, please feel free to suggest edits to this question if I've misused terminology or been otherwise unclear.

Comment: So, when you serialize the XML you want any of those elements who's values match the content of an external entity to be written as an entity reference? By the time the XML is marshalled, the entity references have already been resolved. So, you may need to add some sort of post-processing step to transform the serialized XML and find/replace any of the text with an entity reference if it's value matches.

Comment: @MadsHansen Yes, I believe you've summed up what I'm trying to do. If this isn't something that can be done through the deserialisation process itself, then I might have to leave it, because the deserialiser already takes 30s to process the file I'm working with, and I don't want to make it slower. (The file is over 4 million lines)

Comment: I’m less familiar with .NET API to know what is possible or how difficult it is. So, don’t give up just yet. Let’s see if any .NET gurus have any ideas